# The components of numpy.gradient of a symmetric function are different

Tags: python, numpy, gradient

The gradient of a symmetric function should have same derivatives in all dimensions.
numpy.gradient is providing different components.

Here is a MWE.

```
import numpy as np
x = (-1,0,1)
y = (-1,0,1)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
f = 1/(X*X + Y*Y +1.0)

print(f)
>> [[0.33333333 0.5        0.33333333]
   [0.5        1.         0.5       ]
   [0.33333333 0.5        0.33333333]]
```

This has same values in both dimensions.

But `np.gradient(f)` gives

```
[array([[ 0.16666667,  0.5       ,  0.16666667],
    [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
    [-0.16666667, -0.5       , -0.16666667]]),

 array([[ 0.16666667,  0.        , -0.16666667],
    [ 0.5       ,  0.        , -0.5       ],
    [ 0.16666667,  0.        , -0.16666667]])]
```

Both the components of the gradient are different.

Why so? 
What I am missing in interpretation of the output?

Comment: Because derivatives are computed along a *direction*, this direction also needs to be taken into account when comparing them. The Y component viewed along the Y axis is identical to the X component when viewed along the X axis. i.e. you can see the rotational symmetry of the original function by rotating the Y derivative function 90 degrees clockwise.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Then, how should such a result for a 3 dimensional array looked at?

Comment: In 3D you also have to maintain the *cyclic order* of axes when changing the coordinate system, i.e. view the X component in the XYZ frame, Y in YZX and Z in ZXY.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Yes, this seems to be the case. I think this should be mentioned in the numpy.gradient documentation.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Is there any away to undo this "cycling" and get the derivatives as it is for an n-dimensional array?

Comment: This is just a simple mathematical observation. Why would a math library need to document this? And what do you mean by "undo"?

Comment: I need a 2nd order derivative (gradient)  of a scalar 3D  function. Applying the gradient twice is messing up the results. I just need the gradient values for all dimensions at their respective indexes in the output.

Comment: what do you mean by a second order derivative of a ``f:R3->R``? A gradient is a 1st order derivative. Do you need a divergence? A laplacian?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog. Please write your response as an answer, so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's walk through this step by step. So first, as correctly mentioned by meowgoesthedog
numpy calculates derivatives in a direction.

### Numpy's way of calculating gradients

It's important to note that `np.gradient` uses centric differences meaning  (for simplicity we look at just one direction):

```
grad_f[i] = (f[i+1] - f[i])/2 + (f[i] - f[i-1])/2 =  (f[i+1] - f[i-1])/2
```

At the boundary numpy calculates (take the `min` as example)

```
grad_f[min] = f[min+1] - f[min]
grad_f[max] = f[max] - f[max-1]
```

In your case the boundary is `0` and `2`.

### 2D case

If you use more than one dimension we need to the direction of the derivative into account. `np.gradient` calculates the derivatives in all possible directions. Let's reproduce your results:

Let's move alongside the columns, so we calculate with **row vectors**

```
f[1,:] - f[0,:]
```

Output

```
array([0.16666667, 0.5       , 0.16666667])
```

which is exactly the first row of the first element of your gradient.

The row is calculated with centered derivatives, therefore:

```
(f[2,:]-f[1,:])/2 + (f[1,:]-f[0,:])/2
```

Output

```
array([0., 0., 0.])
```

The third row:

```
f[2,:] - f[1,:]
```

Output

```
array([-0.16666667, -0.5       , -0.16666667])
```

For the other direction just exchange the `:` and the numbers and take in mind that you are now calculating **column vectors**. This leads directly to the **transposed** derivative in the case of a symmetric function, like in your case.

### 3D case

```
x_ = (-1,0,4)
y_ = (-3,0,1)
z_ = (-1,0,12)

x, y, z = np.meshgrid(x_, y_, z_, indexing='ij')
f = 1/(x**2 + y**2 + z**2 + 1)
np.gradient(f)[1]
```

Output

```
array([[[ *2.50000000e-01,  4.09090909e-01,  3.97702165e-04*],
        [ 8.33333333e-02,  1.21212121e-01,  1.75554093e-04],
        [-8.33333333e-02, -1.66666667e-01, -4.65939801e-05]],

       [[ **4.09090909e-01,  9.00000000e-01,  4.03045231e-04**],
        [ 1.21212121e-01,  2.00000000e-01,  1.77904287e-04],
        [-1.66666667e-01, -5.00000000e-01, -4.72366556e-05]],

       [[ ***1.85185185e-02,  2.03619910e-02,  3.28827183e-04***],
        [ 7.79727096e-03,  8.54700855e-03,  1.45243282e-04],
        [-2.92397661e-03, -3.26797386e-03, -3.83406181e-05]]])
```

The gradient which is given here is calculated along rows (`0` would be along matrices, `1` along rows, `2` along columns).

This can be calculated by

```
(f[:,1,:] - f[:,0,:])
```

Output

```
array([[*2.50000000e-01, 4.09090909e-01, 3.97702165e-04*],
       [**4.09090909e-01, 9.00000000e-01, 4.03045231e-04**],
       [***1.85185185e-02, 2.03619910e-02, 3.28827183e-04***]])
```

I added the asteriks so that it becomes clear where to find corresponding row vectors. Since we calculated the gradient in direction `1` we have to look for **row vectors**.

If one wants to reproduce the whole gradient, this is done by

```
np.stack(((f[:,1,:] - f[:,0,:]), (f[:,2,:] - f[:,0,:])/2, (f[:,2,:] - f[:,1,:])), axis=1)
```

### n-dim case

We can generalize the things we learned to here to calculate gradients of arbitrary functions along directions.

```
def grad_along_axis(f, ax):
    f_grad_ind = []
    for i in range(f.shape[ax]):
        if i == 0:
            f_grad_ind.append(np.take(f, i+1, ax) - np.take(f, i, ax))
        elif i == f.shape[ax] -1:
            f_grad_ind.append(np.take(f, i, ax) - np.take(f, i-1, ax))
        else:
            f_grad_ind.append((np.take(f, i+1, ax) - np.take(f, i-1, ax))/2)
    f_grad = np.stack(f_grad_ind, axis=ax)
    return f_grad
```

where

```
np.take(f, i, ax) = f[:,...,i,...,:]
```

and `i` is at index `ax`.

Answer (score 0):

Usually gradients and jacobians are operators on functions

Id you need the gradient of `f = 1/(X*X + Y*Y +1.0)` then you have to compute it symbolically. Or estimate it with numerical methods that use that function.

I do not know what a gradient of a constant 3d array is. `numpy.gradient` is a one dimensional concept.

Python has the sympy package that can automatically compute jacobians symbolically.

If by `second order derivative of a scalar 3d field` you mean a laplacian then you can estimate that with a standard 4 point stencil.